An odd odd one out
Which of the following is the odd one out and why?

Nearly successful actress
Aim in France
Movie Doctor
A type of lute


Should the knowledge tag perhaps be added?


 Nearly successful actress - starlet
 Aim in France - le but
 Movie Doctor - No
 A type of lute - oud

I note that

 starlet is one letter away from scarlet

Possibly more interestingly,

 "but" is one letter away from "out"
 "no" is one letter away from "one"
 "oud" is one letter away from "odd" (or indeed, "out")

So I think that

 starlet is the odd one out because it's not one letter away from the words "odd", "one" or "out".


On the right track but not quite

Looks promising, rot13(lbhe svefg nafjre vf bar yrggre njnl sebz 'yrggref')

I believe the answer is

 Movie doctor

Because

 Taking the first letters of all of them gets you
 • NSA (National Security Agency)
 • AIF (Association of Independent Festivals
 • MD (Doctor of Medicine)
 • ATOL (Air Travellers Organisers Licensing)

And

 Movie Doctor is the only phrase where the first letter of each word stand for a phrase which has a common word with the original phrase (Doctor).


Why a -1? If you’re the OP and you gave the downvote and it’s incorrect then say that it is.

Not the downvoter but a comment by way of feedback: Statistically, the downvote is very unlikely to be from the OP, and is probably just someone passing through and making their own assessment of answer quality based on what they imagine the OP's intent probably is (or at least isn't). Here, those initials could stand for so many different things, e.g. MD = Medical Director, which invalidates your logic. So the rule seems very arbitrary, and a bit like 'the first thing someone thought of' instead of a likely answer to a puzzle by someone who's submitted many puzzles to this site before.

(Plus, across the whole of SE people don't have to explain downvotes, and very often don't. I realise it would be more useful and constructive if they did but that isn't necessarily how the world works, sorry...!)

Not the correct answer unfortunately

I think the answer is

 "A type of lute"

Because

 Nearly successful actress refers to a "starlet," which is a young actress who is on the verge of becoming famous.


 Aim in France translates to the French word "but," which also refers to the goal or aim.


 Movie Doctor could refer to a "doc," which is short for "doctor" but also a common term for a documentary, which is a type of movie.


 A type of lute refers to a "mandolin," which is a stringed musical instrument.

Conclusion

 The first three options are all wordplay or puns that refer to shortened or slang terms (starlet, but, doc), whereas "A type of lute" (mandolin) is a straightforward reference to a musical instrument with no wordplay or pun involved. Thus, it is the odd one out.


The answers of Vicky really helped to puzzle this one together
